# discord.py slash commands not registering

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I've been working on this bot for a few weeks or so and everything was working correctly. I have made some changes to the `main.py` file like editing `Hayate` class getting rid of the `on_ready` function etc. I also changed the `commands.Bot` in the cogs to `Hayate`. Everything was working correctly until a few hours ago when for some reason bot isn't registering slashes anymore? I tried kicking it and adding again, making new aplication etc. but none of this worked. Here is my code:

###### Main.py

```py
import logging

import discord
from config.load_env import bot_token, mongo
from discord.ext import commands

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Define a subclass of the commands.Bot class
class Hayate(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        # Configuration
        allowed_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(roles = False, everyone = False, users = True)
        intents = discord.Intents().all()
        activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.playing, name = f'sucking some smeggsy toes')
        
        super().__init__(
            command_prefix = commands.when_mentioned,
            pm_help = None, 
            activity = activity,
            heartbeat_timeout = 150.0,
            allowed_mentions = allowed_mentions,
            intents = intents
        )

        self.cogslist = [
            'extensions.economy.wallet',
            'extensions.economy.daily',
            'extensions.economy.give',
            'extensions.economy.checklist',
            'extensions.economy.lottery',
            
            'extensions.fun.flags',
            'extensions.fun.emoji',
            'extensions.fun.dice',
            'extensions.fun.ship',

            'extensions.info.github',
            'extensions.info.members', 
            'extensions.info.guild',

            'extensions.utility.ping',
            'extensions.utility.remindme',
            'extensions.utility.time',
            'extensions.utility.info',
            'extensions.utility.snipe',
            'extensions.utility.load',

            'extensions.music.artist'
        ]

    # Define an asynchronous method to load the cogs
    async def setup_hook(self):
        for ext in self.cogslist:
            try:
                await self.load_extension(ext)
                log.info(f'{ext} has been loaded')
            except Exception as e:
                log.exception(f'Failed to load extension {ext}.')

# Configure logging format
logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.INFO,
    format = '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
    datefmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create an instance of the Hayate class and run the bot using a token
    client = Hayate()

    try:
        mongo.admin.command('ping')
        log.info('Successfully connected to MongoDB!')
    except Exception as e:
        log.exception(f'Failed to connect to MongoDB: {e}')

    # Run the bot, and catch any exceptions that may be raised
    try:
        log.info(f'Logged in as Hayate')
        client.run(bot_token)
    except Exception as e:
        log.exception(f'Error: {e}')
```

###### Ping cog (just for example because this one is the least complicated and all the other cogs are created this or very similar way)

```py
import datetime

import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from main import Hayate

class ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client: Hayate):
        self.client: Hayate = client

    @app_commands.command(
        name = 'ping',
        description = 'Returns ping of a current shard.'
    )
    @app_commands.guild_only()
    async def ping(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        ctx = await self.client.get_context(interaction)
        shard_id = ctx.guild.shard_id
        latency = self.client.latency

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = ':ping_pong: Pong!',
            description = f'<:info:1118212340685475861> **Shard ID:** `{shard_id}`\n<:timer:1117463845036892190> **Latency:** `{round(latency * 1000)}ms`',
            color = 0x575fcf,
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()  
        )
        embed.set_footer(
                text = f'Requested by {interaction.user.name}',
                icon_url = interaction.user.avatar
        )

        await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed)

async def setup(client: Hayate) -> None:
    await client.add_cog(ping(client))
```

In advance I'm saying that the folder structure is correct, all the things i store in `.env` are correct too and the logging I'm using in `setup_hook` is returning information that all the cogs were loaded. I tried many things but I didn't came up with solution so I'm turning to you, so please tell me what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync your app commands somewhere. Discord.py does not automatically sync your commands to discord.

Preferably you do not do this in something like `on_ready` or `setup_hook` but in another way. You could use a standard message command to achieve this for example.

If you just call `sync` on your `CommandTree`, it will sync your slash commands globally. Be warned that this may take up to an hour to show up.

A `commands.Bot` automatically has access to a `CommandTree` with `bot.tree`. Since you defined your bot as `client` this would be `client.tree`

```py
@client.command()
async def sync(ctx: commands.Context):
    await client.tree.sync()
```

You can circumvent the hour long wait, if you sync your command to a specific guild. Then they will show up instantly:

```py
@client.command()
async def sync(ctx: commands.Context, guild: discord.Guild):
    await client.tree.sync(guild=guild)
```

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=sync#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.sync